# How can I display times between start and end time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Supposed to be, I have start and end time.

Given Example:

```
var startTime = '12:30 PM';
var endTime = '03:00 AM';
```

Now, I want to display the time between that range with 5 minutes interval, 3 hours additional time from startTime and minus 1 hour for the endTime. So the sample result based on the given time range will be:

```
03:30 PM
03:35 PM
03:40 PM
03:45 PM
03:50 PM
03:55 PM
04:00 PM
04:05 PM
....
....
02:00 AM
```

First time to display will be `03:30 PM` because `12:30 PM + 3 hours = 03:30 PM`

And the last time to display will be `02:00 AM` because `03:00 AM - 1 hour = 02:00 AM`

I'm using moment.js. Here's my code:

```
var startTime = '12:30 PM';
var endTime = '03:00 AM';

var startTime2 = '12:30 PM';
var endTime2 = '05:00 PM';

console.log(intervals(startTime, endTime));      // this is not working
console.log(intervals(startTime2, endTime2));    // this is working

function intervals(start, end) {
  var start = moment(start, 'hh:mm a').add(3, 'h');
  var end = moment(end, 'hh:mm a').subtract(1, 'h');

  var result = [];
  var current = moment(start);
  while (current <= end) {
    result.push(current.format('hh:mm a'));
    current.add(5, 'minutes');
  }
  return result;
}
```

My Problem is that, if the given time

```
var startTime = '12:30 PM';
var endTime = '03:00 AM';
```

will not work. It only works if the given time will be

```
var startTime2 = '12:30 PM';
var endTime2 = '05:00 PM';
```

I think the problem is because of PM-AM periods. How can we solve that? Please help.

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet of what exactly isnt working?

Comment: problem is that your first end time need to have 1 additional day :) so you need to add a day to your end local var if end is less than start.

Comment: What if startTime is `05:00 PM` and endTime is `04:00 PM`. Can you simply make assumption that if the endtime is smaller than starttime then it is of next day?

Comment: Yah, that's it.  I just need to add additional 1 day if endtime is smaller than starttime. But how?

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of an identical question that has since been deleted. Given that this one has an accepted answer, I believe it should be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have this one condition as well:

```
  if(end < start)
    end = end.add(1, 'd');
```

Check the complete code below:

```js
var startTime = '12:30 PM';
var endTime = '03:00 AM';

var startTime2 = '12:30 PM';
var endTime2 = '05:00 PM';

console.log(intervals(startTime, endTime));      // this is not working
console.log(intervals(startTime2, endTime2));    // this is working

function intervals(start, end) {
  var start = moment(start, 'hh:mm a').add(3, 'h');
  var end = moment(end, 'hh:mm a').subtract(1, 'h');
  if(end < start)
    end = end.add(1, 'd');
  var result = [];
  var current = moment(start);
  while (current <= end) {
    result.push(current.format('hh:mm a'));
    current.add(5, 'minutes');
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Alright! that's it. Thank you. its working.  Keep Sharing :)